# Implicit differentiation in terms of x, y, r and f

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I just want to check am I practicing implicit differentiation correctly.

$$r = x+f(y+ rx + x^3)$$

where f is a differentiable function.

I am trying to use implicit differentiation to find $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ in terms of $y,\ x,\ r$ and $f$.

$$\therefore\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial [x+f(y+ rx + x^3)]}{\partial x}$$

$$= 1+ \frac{\partial f(y+ rx + x^3)}{\partial x}$$

$$= 1+ f^\prime(y+ rx + x^3)\cdot\frac{\partial (y+ rx + x^3)}{\partial x}$$

$f^\prime$ replaces $f^\prime(y+ rx + x^3)$ for brevity.

$$=1 + f^\prime\cdot 
 \left[ 0 + \frac{ \partial (rx) } { \partial x  } + \frac{ \partial (x^3) } { \partial x  }  \right]
$$

$$=1 + f^\prime\cdot 
 \left[x\cdot\frac{ \partial r } { \partial x  } + r +  3x^2  \right]
$$

$$\therefore\frac{ \partial r } { \partial x  } = 1 + f^\prime\cdot x\cdot\frac{ \partial r } { \partial x  } + f^\prime\cdot r\ +  f^\prime\cdot 3x^2
$$

$$\implies\frac{ \partial r } { \partial x  }\cdot 
 \left[1 - f^\prime\cdot x\  \right] = 1 + f^\prime\cdot\left[ r\ + 3x^2 \right]
$$

$$\therefore\frac{ \partial r } { \partial x  } = \frac{1 + f^\prime\cdot\left[ r\ + 3x^2 \right]}{\left[1 - f^\prime\cdot x\  \right]}
$$

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Looks good to me (provided of course that $y$ is not dependent on $x$).